# R Prevent Lazyeval

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I want to use `high()` from the `rPref` library with changing variable names, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,0))
psel(df, high(x) * high(y))
```

But if I did not know the column names beforehand, I tried this

```
psel(df, Reduce("*", sapply(colnames(df), high)))
```

which gives

```
Error in calc_scores(object, df, frm) : 
  For the high preference high(X[[i]]) the expression must be numeric!
```

I tried `force()` but it does not help here

**Edit**: Nevermind, I realized `rPref` also has `high_()` for standard evaluation..